# Why I am getting error "Duplicate names are not allowed"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


u_cols = ['user_id', 'age', 'sex', 'occupation', 'zip_code']
users = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.user', sep='|', names=u_cols, encoding='latin-1')


r_cols = ['user_id','movie_id','rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep="\t", names=r_cols, encoding='latin-1')
```

Comment: Please someone help me what silly mistake I am doing in code

Comment: which line causes the error? does one of the input csv files have two columns with the same title?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to change the version, your problem will be resolved just copy paste the given code:

`FOR TRAIN SLOT`

```py
X_train = pd.read_csv('../UCI_HAR_Dataset/train/X_train.txt',
delim_whitespace=True, header=None, encoding='latin-1')
X_train.columns = features
```

`FOR TEST SLOT`

```py
X_test = pd.read_csv('UCI-HAR-Dataset/test/X_test.txt', 
delim_whitespace=True, header=None, encoding='latin-1')
X_test.columns = features
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this version of pandas

```
pip install pandas==0.20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

we can able to resolve issue like this, no need of version change.

```
X_train = pd.read_csv('../UCI_HAR_Dataset/train/X_train.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None, encoding='latin-1')
X_train.columns = features
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would solve the issue?

Comment: I also dont know the reason but this is working, if anyone can explain it would be good.

Answer (score 0):

It can be that the csv file itself has duplications in the column names.

Comment: If that's the case, use the 'usecols' param to specify the columns in the csv you want to use. For example `r_cols = ['user_id','movie_id','rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep="\t", usecols=[0,1,3,4], names=r_cols, encoding='latin-1')`

Answer (score 0):

I have to movielens dataset to hand, but don't get any error using your code to load it:

```
u_cols = ['user_id', 'age', 'sex', 'occupation', 'zip_code']
users = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.user', sep='|', names=u_cols, encoding='latin-1')

r_cols = ['user_id','movie_id','rating', 'unix_timestamp']
ratings = pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep="\t", names=r_cols, encoding='latin-1')

users.head()
Out[36]: 
   user_id  age sex  occupation zip_code
0        1   24   M  technician    85711
1        2   53   F       other    94043
2        3   23   M      writer    32067
3        4   24   M  technician    43537
4        5   33   F       other    15213

ratings.head()
Out[37]: 
   user_id  movie_id  rating  unix_timestamp
0      196       242       3       881250949
1      186       302       3       891717742
2       22       377       1       878887116
3      244        51       2       880606923
4      166       346       1       886397596
```